# How to get JS file to work in Safari Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

A script I have found to randomly change the position of div's in my website does not work properly in Safari browsers. I can see that the element style position is being updated live when inspecting, but the change in position is not being rendered in the dom.

```
        function randomFromTo(from, to){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
        }
  
        function moveRandom(obj) {
            /* get container position and size
             * -- access method : cPos.top and cPos.left */
            var cPos = $('.sphere-move-container').offset();
            var cHeight = $('.sphere-move-container').height();
            var cWidth = $('.sphere-move-container').width();
            
            // get box padding (assume all padding have same value)
            var pad = parseInt($('.sphere-move-container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));
            
            // get movable box size
            var bHeight = obj.height();
            var bWidth = obj.width();
            
            // set maximum position
            maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight - pad;
            maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth - pad;
            
            // set minimum position
            minY = cPos.top + pad;
            minX = cPos.left + pad;
            
            // set new position         
            newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
            newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);
            
            obj.animate({
                top: newY,
                left: newX
                }, 10000, function() {
          moveRandom(obj);
            });
        }
$('.category-sphere-container').each(function() {
moveRandom($(this));
});
```

Script renders in chrome, firefox etc. I've been unable to determine how to edit script so that it works in Safari. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may not be the problem, but the "max", "min", and "new" variables should all be declared (with `let` or `var` or `const`, as appropriate).

Comment: Thanks Pointy! That's great to know.

It's still not rendering the new div position in Safari after declaring the variables. But I can see the Element Style Attribute 'top' and 'left' positions are updating correctly.